# How does choosing a team (colour) that is strong in my area affects endgame gameplay?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it beneficial to join a strong team? Do I get any valuable bonuses (lure modules installed in your area worth it?) from high-level friendly gyms?

Or is it better to choose weaker team in order to have more opportunities to fight?

Does the choice matter for endgame (level 20+ let's say)?

Comment: the linked question is related, but does not contain answer I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think they are all the same when it comes to the type of pokemon that you encounter but as for your gym battling experience, the only difference I that you are battling opposing teams. I believe it is more of a competitive type of deal between teams like a sport.

Comment: Thanks, but I still suspect there might be a factor in lure modules being installed in the area.

Comment: @jediz: What does lure modules have to do with teams? Lure modules benefit every player at that particular Pokestop.

Comment: @Ellesedil that is the piece I was missing it seems!

Comment: ***Disclaimer:** If you don't join your friends' team, then you may lose friends.*

Answer (score 0):

With how defending and attacking works there are advantages and disadvantages to both.

When attacking an enemy gym you have 6 Pokémon to fight with, but defending you only have 1, this means you can get to the higher CP Pokémon of a gym and lower it's prestige more with each battle. Compared to just defending you won't raise it's prestige as far since you are limited to only one Pokémon for the battle. Also if you take into account that 2 teams will be attacking (lowering prestige) and only 1 team is defending (raising prestige) it should always be easier to take out and take over enemy gyms than it is to continue defending them.

Alternatively with a more popular and more populated team in your area you can raise it's prestige much faster and higher together than enemy teams could if they are not represented. For example if you had a dozen people on team A attacking or powering up gyms, you could keep a Pokémon there longer and receive the rewards longer. But if you only have 2 people on team B they will always be playing catch up, trying to get to the next gym and retake it again. There is also the fact that with less people you will probably have less Pokémon for your team to defend (since you can only have 1 Pokémon per account at a single gym).

Not to mention there is a possible social aspect as well. Going up to a group of people at a gym they might be more friendly if you are there to help them keep the gym, as opposed to if you were there to screw them over and take it for your team.

Simply put, it is meant to be easier for the enemy teams to always take over a gym so that gyms can continuously change and be fought over, but with enough of an advantage a team can easily outnumber and almost permanently hold gyms. It's up to you which you want but in the long run it shouldn't matter and most surveys show there isn't a big enough difference in numbers in populated ares to make a difference. Personally I think go with what your friends have picked or whichever looks cooler to you.

Answer (score 0):

It should not affect gameplay, since lure modules are beneficial for everybody and all the rest is insignificant in terms of gameplay mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, when you say stronger team I'm going to assume you mean the team with the most players, in that case it would be blue. The blue team holds roughly 43% of the player count in the game. So by numbers this team could be considered the strongest.

Whether it's yours or the opposing teams gym you still are able to fight. Fighting your own gym successfully raises the reputation of that gym eventually leveling it up so that you can place more pokemon in it at once.

Lure modules have nothing to do with which team you are on, and no matter who installs one it positively affects everyone nearby. So which team you choose will not affect the amount of lure modules that you encounter.

Comment: Note: It's not blue team, it's Team Mystic. Also, he means in his **area**, not globally or "in the game" like you said.

Comment: I believe when he said area he was referring to lure modules, which as I stated, will not be affected by the chosen team